# Can not replace multiple empty lines with one

Tags: regex, perl

Why does the following not replace multiple empty lines with one?

```
$ cat some_random_text.txt  
foo   



bar   




test
```

and this does not work:

```
$ cat some_random_text.txt | perl -pe "s/\n+/\n/g"
foo  



bar  





test
```

I am trying to replace the multiple new lines (i.e. empty lines) to a single empty new line but the regex I use for that does not work as you can see in the example snippet.
What am I messing up?

Expected outcome is:

```
foo

bar

test
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason it doesn't work is that `-p` tells perl to process the input line by line, and there's never more than one `\n` in a single line.

Better idea:

```
perl -00 -lpe 1
```

- `-00`: Enable paragraph mode (input records are terminated by any sequence of 2+ newlines).
- `-l`: Enable autochomp mode (the input record separators are trimmed automatically, so since we're in paragraph mode, all trailing newlines are removed, and output records get `"\n\n"` added).
- `-p`: Enable automatic input/output (the main code is executed for each input record; anything left in `$_` is printed automatically).
- `-e 1`: Use a dummy main program that does nothing.

Taken all together this does nothing except normalize paragraph terminators to exactly two newlines.

Comment: This is interesting and it works but don't get me wrong, it seems like a black box approach. I mean on first sight it is very hard to understand (may be I am wrong here) what the code does piping to that command

Comment: Note: This leaves two line feeds at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the following program:

```
LINE: while (<>) {
   s/\n+/\n/g;
}
continue {
   die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Since you are reading one line at at time, and since a line is a sequence of characters that aren't line feeds terminated by a line feed, your pattern will never match more than one newline.

---

The simple fix is to tell Perl to treat the entire file as one line. Also, you don't want to replace every line feed, but just those found in sequence of two or more, and you want to replace the sequence with two line feeds.

```
perl -0777pe's/\n\n\K\n+//g; s^\n+//; s/\n\K\n\z//' some_random_text.txt
```

The second and third substitutions ensure there are no blank lines at the start and end of the file.

---

While reading the entire file into memory is easy, it's not necessary. The desired output can also be achieved by maintaining a flag that indicates whether the previous line was blank or not.

```
perl -ne'if (/\S/) { print "\n" if $f; print; $f=0 } else { $f=1 }' some_random_text.txt
```

This solution also removes blank lines from the start and end of the file.

Comment: The expected output uses `\n\n` , not `\n`.

Comment: @choroba, Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami:Is there a reason that you are not separating `-0777` with `pe` and the pattern with a space?

Comment: @ikegami: I understood your first snippet! Very useful thank you!!! I do not understand the second one though. Could you please elaborate? I think it tries to check `if` is not whitespace but not sure about the rest

Comment: Why would I want to write `-0777 -p -e` instead of `-0777pe`?

Comment: If the current line contains a non-whitespace character, print a blank line if necessary, and print the line. Otherwise, set a flag indicating a blank line is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
foo   



bar   




test
```

You can use `sed` to reduce the runs of blank lines to a single `\n`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | sed '/^$/N;/^\n$/D'
foo   

bar   

test
```

Even easier, you can use `cat -s`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | cat -s            # same output
```

In `perl` the idiomatic 1 liner is to use `-00` for paragraph mode:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -00pe0       # same output
```

And in `awk` you have the flexibility of using paragraph mode by setting `RS=` and then set `ORS=` to what you want the replacement for runs of `\n` to be:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '1' RS= ORS="\n\n"    # same output
```

---

ikegami correctly states that `printf 'a\n\n' | ...` will produce two trailing spaces with these solutions. That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Note: Both solutions can leave two line feeds at the end of the file